# Make AP client connect to another AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Is it possible to deauth client from my wifi AP and make it connect to another AP?
Both APs can be trusted, only reason to do this is that I need to balance amount of clients connected to one AP.
Shutting down the first AP for a while to wait for client to connect to the second AP is not the option since there are other clients connected.
And both APs are running Linux.

Comment: Why should you deauth an existing client to connect it to another AP? Why can't the next client to connect connect to the other AP that has free connections? A maxed-out AP should prevent connections anyway? If you do want to do this then you could set up MAC filtering for known devices that you allow to your AP.

Comment: Thank you, MAC filtering could do the work. If I deauth the client and set up a MAC filter for it, client will automatically connect to another AP with same known SSID, right?

Comment: Should do, yes.